# Overall rank from multiple ranked lists

Tags: algorithm, methods, statistics

I've looked through a lot of literature available online, including this forum without any luck and hoping someone can help a statistical issue I currently face:

I have 5 lists of of ranked data, each containing 10 items ranked from position 1 (best) to position 10 (worst). For sake of context, the 10 items in each lists are the same, but in different ranked orders as the technique used to decide their rank is different.

*Example data:
            List 1      List 2      List 3     ... etc

Item 1     Ranked 1    Ranked 2    Ranked 1

Item 2     Ranked 3    Ranked 1    Ranked 2

Item 3     Ranked 2    Ranked 3    Ranked 3

... etc*

I am looking for a way to interpret and analyse the above data so that I get a final result showing the overall rank of each item based on each test and its position, e.g.

Result

Rank 1 = Item 1

Rank 2 = Item 3

Rank 3 = Item 4

... etc

Does anyone know how I can interpret this data in a statistically sound method (at a post graduate / PhD applicable level) so that I can understand the overall ranks signalling the importance of each item in the list across the 5 tests please? Or, if there is another type of technique or statistical test I can look into I would appreciate any hints or guidance.

(It maybe also worth noting, I have also performed the simpler mathematical techniques such as sums, averaging, minimum - maximum tests etc, but do not feel these are statistically important enough at this level).

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use machine learning to get your ranked list. In the Information Retrieval research field - this is called [**Learning to Rank**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank) - and there is a wide rage of literature about it. [This tutorial](http://www2009.org/pdf/T7A-LEARNING%20TO%20RANK%20TUTORIAL.pdf) (heads up: high level tutorial) can help you understand the basic concepts and point you to articles for deepening in.
2. You might also want to have a look on [interleaved ranking](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=179433). This was originally engineered for *evaluation* of two lists, but it might also be good for your case.

Answer (score 0):

A number of non-parametric statistical tests work by turning the data received into ranks and then analysing the ranks (this can make life easier if the data are very far from being normally distributed). If your ranks are plausibly derived from some underlying score or goodness that you can't observe directly, you could apply any of these tests - there is a short list at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Ranking_in_statistics or any book on non-parametric statistics, such as Conover, should cover them.

If you can come up with a statistic you are interested in, such as the total rank of any one item, you could use a Permutation Test - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29#Permutation_tests to work out the probability that the statistic concerned is at least as extreme as observed, under the probability that all of the rankings are simply random - you just generate loads of data that follows the null hypothesis and look at the distribution of the statistic in the randomly generated data. You can then use this to get a P-value, or, better, a confidence bound.